# How do I do an insert with DATETIME now inside of SQL server mgmt studio

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a website that does inserts into this table below.  I need to do some manual inserts but I wasn't sure how do pass in the equivalent of DateTime.Now in C#.

I am running this below from the query editor in SQL server mgmt studio.  Is there any way to pass in the current date time in this query below.

```
INSERT INTO [Business]
           ([IsDeleted]
           ,[FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[LastUpdated]
           ,[LastUpdatedBy])
     VALUES
           (0, 'Joe', 'Thomas', 
           ,<LastUpdated, datetime,>
           ,<LastUpdatedBy, nvarchar(50),>)
```

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Use [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) (or GETDATE() on archaic versions of SQL Server).

Comment: "This function is the ANSI SQL equivalent to GETDATE." It's non-ANSI, not prehistoric

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to write non-standard SQL when the standard version works just as well.

Comment: @CraigStuntz so CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the ANSI version, correct?

Answer (score 62):

Just use `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()` (if you want to get the "universal" UTC time, instead of your local server's time-zone related time).

```
INSERT INTO [Business]
           ([IsDeleted]
           ,[FirstName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[LastUpdated]
           ,[LastUpdatedBy])
     VALUES
           (0, 'Joe', 'Thomas', 
           GETDATE(),  <LastUpdatedBy, nvarchar(50),>)
```