# Mongo insert $currentDate in Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I've got a question about  [$currentDate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)
What is the best way to insert a document in mongo db so that it contains the "server time" (like ''now()'' in some RDBMSs) using the Java Driver?

For example, lest say I have a document like:

```
{
     name : "John",
     birthday : <$currentDate_goes_here>
}
```

What I want is to insert the document so that the evaluation of the date would be done by **mongo server** at the time of insertion on the server side.

This is critical because our servers might not be totally synchronized and there is a need to have the time we can rely on (for example the time on mongo server).

I'm using a standard java driver for mongo, so any code snippet in Java will be more than welcome.

This is what I've tried so far

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 DB sampleDB = mongoClient.getDB("sampleDB");
 BasicDBObject update = 
          new BasicDBObject("$set", new     BasicDBObject("name","john")
              .append("$currentDate", new BasicDBObject("birthday",true)));
sampleDB.getCollection("col1").insert(update);
```

This thing fails on the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document field names can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$set')
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.validateKey(DBCollection.java:1845)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkKeys(DBCollection.java:1803)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection._checkObject(DBCollection.java:1790)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.applyRulesForInsert(DBCollectionImpl.java:392)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:381)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:186)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)

Comment: So do you understand what [$currentDate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) actually does? The point is to create a "current timestamp" at the "actual" time of insertion of the document. You seem to be asking for something completely different considering your naming of "birthday". despite your additional explanation.

Comment: I'm asking about the way to create a document that contains the date (and time) of the mongo server. In RDBMS I would do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072078/how-do-i-do-an-insert-with-datetime-now-inside-of-sql-server-mgmt-studio But I don't know how to do that in mongo. the birthday doesn't really matter, its just an example of something that should be a date/time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In which case the answer is fairly simple. It is really about serializing from java `BasicDBObject` classes to the basic MongoDB interpretation. Without respect to your actual "query" document the "update" document part of your statement should be:

```
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("name","john")
        .append("$currentDate", new BasicDBObject("birthrhday",true))
    ;
```

Which will indeed use the "server time" at the point of "update insertion" or "modification" with respect to the [**`$currentDate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) modifier as used.

Just to be clear here, you don't use the `.insert()` method but an ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option)operation with `.insert()`. The "query" and "update" syntax applies. Also see the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator for specifically not modifying existing documents.

Comment: I couldn't __insert__ the data, it looks like it works for update only. an Attempt to insert the data has resulted the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document field names can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$set')" exception. I've updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @MarkBramnik Yes it is an update operator only, but you can use "upsert" as an option to facilitate inserts. So yes you can insert data this way,

Answer (score -1):

You can also use aggregation variable "$$NOW" if you are using an aggregation pipeline with `update` method.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB sampleDB = mongoClient.getDB("sampleDB");
BasicDBObject update = 
          new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("name","john")
              .append("birthday", new BsonString("$$NOW")));
sampleDB.getCollection("col1").updateOne(query, List.of(update));
```

You can also use `"$$NOW"` with aggregation operators such as `$add`, `$subtract`, and many more, to compute more specific values (including dates) on the database side.

Comment: This will set birthday to the string value "$$NOW", not the timestamp.

Comment: My bad... apparently the "List.of" helps signify aggregation pipeline, which makese $$NOW work.  So strange.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass the Application Server's time instead of Database time, use the following code to send the current time. You should decide whether to use this in case if the Application Server time differs from Database Server time.

```
new BsonDateTime(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
```

Sample Code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB sampleDB = mongoClient.getDB("sampleDB");
BasicDBObject update = 
          new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("name","john")
              .append("birthday", new BsonDateTime(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())));
sampleDB.getCollection("col1").updateOne(query, update);
```

Comment: OP explicitly asked to use the database server timestamp and not the application server timestamp.