# Inserting datetime value into the database with EF-CodeFirst seed data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to seed my database with some data. The error I get is on the boolean and datefields. Below is the sample seed data for seeding the database. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
 Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (1, 'SomeFirstName', 'SomeSurName', 'name@somedomainname.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, True, convert(datetime, '17/07/2017 17:56:25'), null, 1)");
 Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (2, 'SomeFirstName', 'SomeSurName', 'name@somedomainname.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, True, convert(datetime, '17/07/2017 17:56:25'), null, 2)");
 Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (3, 'SomeFirstName', 'SomeSurName', 'name@somedomainname.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, True, convert(datetime, '17/07/2017 17:56:25'), null, 3)");
```

Below is the table structure where I need to populate the seed data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
                        [Id]             TINYINT        NOT NULL,
                        [FirstName]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
                        [LastName]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
                        [Email]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
                        [RefIndicator]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
                        [TeamId]         TINYINT        NOT NULL,
                        [IsRegistered]   BIT            NOT NULL,
                        [DateRegistered] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
                        [LastModified]   DATETIME       NULL,
                        [UserRolesId]    TINYINT        DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
                        CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
                        CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Teams_TeamId] FOREIGN KEY ([TeamId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Teams] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
                        CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Users_dbo.UserRoles_UserRolesId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserRolesId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
                    );


                    GO
                    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TeamId]
                        ON [dbo].[Users]([TeamId] ASC);


                    GO
                    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRolesId]
                        ON [dbo].[Users]([UserRolesId] ASC);
```

Comment: `True` is not a database type. You should have a `bit` column, and send `1` for `true`, or `0` for `false`.

Comment: @krillgar Let em add the table structure here so you may understand where I'm coming from

Comment: @krillgar I have updated the question to reflect the table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully seeded the database with the code below

```
        Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (1, 'SampleName', 'SampleSurname', 'someNames@nnxg.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, 'True', GETDATE(), null, 1)");
        Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (2, 'SampleName', 'SampleSurname', 'someNames@nnxg.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, 'True', GETDATE(), null, 2)");
        Sql("INSERT INTO USERS (Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,RefIndicator,TeamId,IsRegistered,DateRegistered,LastModified,UserRolesId) VALUES (3, 'SampleName', 'SampleSurname', 'someNames@nnxg.com', 'IMT/iTC22', 1, 'True', GETDATE(), null, 3)");
```

I changed the string value of True to boolean value 'True' and also used the GETDATE() function to insert the current datetime value into the database. I picked up the date solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072078/how-do-i-do-an-insert-with-datetime-now-inside-of-sql-server-mgmt-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert the value `True` into the `IsRegistered` column which is of type `bit`. You're executing a script string, so the C# boolean value of `true`, is not being sent, but a string `True` **that is not wrapped in single quotes** is being sent. That's why both values are throwing the error.

Replace your `True` with `1` in your strings, and you'll be fine.